# Label with measurements doesn't show in label

Tags: python, tkinter, label, sensors

I'am trying to get the results of a temperaturesensor in a label that's on my canvas.
however when i try to put the code for the label and for the measurements togheter my label doesn't show on my canvas. I've already tried to make the results into a string or integer but all this doesn't work.

I hope somebody can help me, thanks in advance.

below is the code that I use.

````
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL.ImageTk import PhotoImage
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import Entry, END, Frame, Toplevel, StringVar
from tkinter import Label
from w1thermsensor import W1ThermSensor


root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=420, background="Black")
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(400, 240)

sensor1 = W1ThermSensor(id="first-sensor-id")
temperature = sensor1.get_temperature()


Label3 = Label(text="temperature")
Label3_window = canvas.create_window(100, 100, anchor="nw", window=Label3)

root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Should `Label3 = Label(text="temperature")` be `Label3 = Label(text=temperature)` instead?

Comment: I already tried that and got the same result, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I have tried your code with hard-coded temperature, i.e. for example `temperature = '21'`, and using `Label3 = tk.Label(text=temperature)`, `21` is shown in the canvas.